# Retrieving average cost

Tags: sql, nested, average, firebird

UPDATE: yes, the result is for a single record. I want to put this on a "computed by" field in firebird (PRODUCTS.PRODU_AVGCOST). It just takes the last 3 buyings for a product and calculates the average cost of it.

I have three tables, witch follows the revelant fields:

```
PRODUCTS
PRODU_ID PK,
PRODU_AVGCOST calculated

BUYINGS
BUYIN_ID PK

BUYING_ITENS
ITEN_ID PK,
ITEN_BUYING_ID FK
ITEN_COST numeric
```

I want to take the average cost of last three buyings from `ITEN_COST` field, using "select" for the `PRODU_AVGCOST` field of the `PRODUCTS` table

I tried as follows on table `PRODUCTS`, but this didn't work

```
select avg(iten_cost) from buying_itens b
where (select first 3 (iten_cost) from buying_itens where c.iten_id = produ_id)
order by b.iten_id desc
```

Comment: Note that if something doesn't work, then also include the error message (which in this case is probably a token unknown (syntax error) as your query does not follow any valid SQL syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this for a single product (assuming `ACTUAL_PRODU_ID` is that value), you can do:

```
select avg(a.iten_cost)
from (
  select first 3 iten_cost
  from buying_itens 
  where produ_id = ACTUAL_PRODU_ID
  order by iten_id desc
) a
```

As far as I can tell the datamodel in your question is not complete (or I fail to see how `products` and `buying_itens` are linked), so I have 'added' `produ_id` to `buying_itens`.

If you want to do this for all products in a single query, things get more complicated.